# Session value is not storing in the variable, not even in tmp folder. Why?

Tags: php, session

Please note that I have started session in both of the pages, but I am still having the problem.

I have saved some value in a session variable, and then echo it on another page, but it always shows empty value, even I have tried the same thing on a different server, where it runs perfectly, it is just creating on client's server. I have searched about this, someone says the values is not storing in tmp folder. I don't know what to do.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    include_once("config.php");
    if(isset($_POST['book'])):
                $_SESSION['tripcode']="hello";      //Test value            
                forceRedirectAdmin("login.php");            
    endif;
?>
```

I echo the session value on login.php page, but it shows empty, even I have included config.php file in login page also.

Comment: i have already mentioned this thing above, yes i did

Comment: i have already started the session in config file, and it is included in both of the pages, but still showing empty value.. why???

Comment: What happens if you `print_r()` the `$_SESSION` super-global?

Comment: Are you getting `$_POST['tripcode']` value??

Comment: Please check if any output is sent before you use session_start(), turn error reporting on and also display errors for your check

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.